# How to get gofstat from fitted models by group in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, goodness-of-fit

I have a large data set comprised of thousands of unique tests (TestNum) and their associated responses (Response), with responses varying in lengths across tests. Tests are dropped out based on some criteria, hence the lack of sequence in TestNum values. Here a simplified example:

```
dat <- data.frame(Response=c(rlnorm(10, 2.9, 0.3), rlnorm(14, 2.88, 0.38), rlnorm(19, 2.44, 0.08)),TestNum=rep(c(1,4,9), times=c(10,14,19)))
dat$TestNum<-factor(dat$TestNum)
dat
```

I am fitting a lnorm distribution to each TestNum and extracting coefficients

```
dat_fit1 <- with(dat,
        by(dat[,1], TestNum, fitdist, "lnorm"))
dat_fit2 <-t(sapply(dat_fit1, coef))
```

I want to test other distributions, but would need the Goodness-of-fit statistics (gofstat; for example "chi"chisqpvalue", "cvm", "ad", "ks", "aic", "bic") from each fitted curve by TestNum. I can get the "aic" and "bic" with the code below, but not the rest of the statistics.

```
gof_f<-do.call(rbind, dat_fit1) 
gof_f<-gof_f[,7:8]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
dat.lnorm <- with(dat,
              by(dat[,1], dat[,2], 
        function(x){
        fit<-fitdist(x,"lnorm", method="mme")                                   
        coef_meanlog <-fit[[1]][[1]]
        coef_sdlog   <-fit[[1]][[2]]
        ks <-ks.test(jitter(x),"plnorm", meanlog=coef_meanlog, sdlog=coef_sdlog)$p.value
        ad <-ad.test(plnorm(x, meanlog=coef_meanlog, sdlog=coef_sdlog))$p.value
        return(list(cbind(rbind(fit[7:8]), ks, ad)))
}))
```